# Excel VBA - Selection Cut Paste Error

Tags: vba, excel, copy-paste

I am creating a macro but I am stuck at this cut paste statement and not able to proceed since yesterday.

Here is the problem: I am selecting all the rows in column "D2 to F2" and pasting it at "A1".
Here is the code for it :

```
Range("D2:F2").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.Cut

Range("A1").Select
Selection.End(xlDown).Select
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
```

Getting this Error:
 [image: Error]

Here's what I have tried :

1. Code Change: Using `PasteSpecial` instead of simple `Paste`.

   ```
   Range("D2:F2").Select
   Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
   Selection.Cut

   Range("A1").Select
   Selection.End(xlDown).Select
   ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
   'ActiveSheet.Paste  ' insted of this using paste special.
   ActiveSheet.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
   ```

Getting the following error:
 [image]

2. Code Change: Resized the selection to 3 columns.

   ```
   Range("D2:F2").Select
   Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
   Selection.Cut

   Range("A1").Select
   Selection.End(xlDown).Select
   ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Resize(1, 3).Select
   'ActiveSheet.Paste
   ```

Getting this error:
 [image]

3. Tried `On Error Resume Next` statement. It is ignoring the error message but not pasting the data as well.

---

I am looking for a way to ignore this error message and proceed with paste. We normally get this error when we manually `copy-paste` or `cut-paste` in excel sheet, there we have option to ignore and paste data. Similarly is there any method to ignore it within a macro?

Comment: Don't use `Select`.

Comment: I'm pretty sure your original selection to copy goes all the way to teh bottom of the worksheet. Because of this, the copied cells are too large to fit into the target. . See [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA macros](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros) for more on getting away from relying on select and activate to accomplish your goals.

Comment: Use only the single top-left cell to designate a target paste area for the copied cells.

Comment: giving it a try, will keep you updated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Avoid `Select` at all costs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros).  Try something like this instead

```
Sub foo()
Dim rng
Set rng = Range("D2:F" & GetLastRow(4))

rng.Cut
Application.Goto Range("A1").Offset(GetLastRow(1))
ActiveSheet.Paste

End Sub

Function GetLastRow(col As Long)
' modified from:
' https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-in-finding-last-used-cell-in-vba

If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Columns(col)) <> 0 Then
    GetLastRow = Columns(col).Find(What:="*", _
                  After:=Cells(Rows.Count, col), _
                  Lookat:=xlPart, _
                  LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                  SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                  SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                  MatchCase:=False).Row
Else
    GetLastRow = 1
End If

End Function
```

Comment: I am getting "Object doesn't support this property or method." error (I have data in `D2:F10`) in `Range("A1").Paste`. Any guess what is wrong?

Comment: Try `Set rng = Range(rng.Address, rng.End(xlDown).Address)`

Comment: @RCaetano I am also getting the same but was trying to figure. Thanks you asked it. I will try david 's suggestion

Comment: the assignment to `rng` object works correctly, which line is raising the error?

Comment: @DavidZemens Range("A1").Paste is causing the error.

Comment: What is below range D2:F2 in the sheet? Do you have any merged cells?

Comment: @ExcelDevelopers its very high 1048576.

Comment: Try another revision, though I don't think that would make a difference if you select the single cell "A2" , etc., you should still be able to paste 3 columns there. However, if there are merged cells in column A, or if part of column A is locked/protected, then you may get a 1004.

Comment: @DavidZemens The problem is I don't want to paste on `Range("A1")`, I want to come end blank row or `A1` and then paste the selected data. 
Your selection thing is perfect. Even paste is perfect only if i want to paste to `A1` but as soon as I apply `End(xlDown)` and `Offset` its beaks :(

Comment: Then the problem would seem to be that the range you're *cutting* is too big to fit in the destination. Too many rows, will exceed the limit of the worksheet, and raise the 1004 error.

Comment: I made a revision to get the last row more appropriately, however this can still fail if the sheet cannot accommodate the pasted data (i.e., if the cut range, when pasted, would overflow the available rows in the worksheet).

Comment: Yeah! This one worked :). Just changed `GetLastRow = 2` in `GetLastRow` function as I need results starting from 2nd row. Thank you very much :). Could you please tell me what exactly `Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Columns(col))` does?

Comment: @SandeepKushwah the [COUNTA](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/COUNTA-function-7dc98875-d5c1-46f1-9a82-53f3219e2509) function counts the number of non-empty cells in a range.

Comment: @DavidZemens : Why you passed `4` in the function argument? Should it be `6` for F right?

Comment: @SandeepKushwah For my testing, I assumed that columns D, E and F all contained the same number of data rows in which case the choice of column number won't matter. If you need to scan from Column F (maybe Column D has not as much data?) then yes, you'll need to use 6 as the argument..

Comment: @DavidZemens Thanks! got the concept.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124459/discussion-between-sandeep-kushwah-and-david-zemens).

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in other answers and comments avoid the use of `.Select` at all costs. It is the source of many common errors. The next solution finds the last row with data by using a simple function.

```
Option Explicit

Function lastrow(rng_str As String)

    ' Adapted from http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s9/win005.htm
    Dim rng As Range: Set rng = Range(rng_str)
    Dim r As Range
    lastrow = rng.Column

    With ActiveSheet
        For Each r In rng.Columns
            lastrow = Application.Max(lastrow, .Cells(.Rows.Count, r.Column).End(xlUp).Row)
        Next
    End With

End Function

Sub test()

    Dim source_rng As Range
    Dim dest_rng As Range
    Dim nr_rows As Long

    ' Maximum number of rows from D to F
    nr_rows = lastrow("D2:F2")

    Set source_rng = Range("D2:F" & nr_rows)
    Set dest_rng = Range("A1")

    source_rng.Cut
    dest_rng.Activate
    ActiveSheet.Paste

End Sub
```

HTH ;)

Comment: Thanks for your efforts! The approach was correct just implementing the same in paste selection would have resulted in the SOLUTION. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are trying to select a cell, which is one cell below the end of the table. After the stop, you have an offset, which gives you one cell lower. Check this out:

```
Option Explicit
Sub test()
    Range("D2:F2").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.Cut

    Range("A1").Select
    Selection.End(xlDown).Select

    Debug.Print ActiveCell.Address
    Stop

    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste

End Sub
```

And, as already said, try to avoid select.

Comment: Thank you @vityata for your effort. Your answer taught me about `Debug.print.`